# Changing sessions values

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm making a page which allow users to change their password. But the password is part of my sessions.

Here are my sessions:

```
$_SESSION['myid'] = $myid;
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
```

I'm saving the username, password and the ID of a user to my sessions. I got a check on every page which checks if the sessions is true:

```
require ('../handlers/loginhandler.php');

session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['myid'])){  //in this part I skipped the username and password

    header("a page");

    }

    else {

    my page 

    }
```

Now when I want to change the password my loginhandler seems to be incorrect. So I need to restart the session and put the new password value in the session. But I can't seem to get it work.

Is it possible for me to put only the user_id in a sessions so my loghandler will stay the same no matter what value I change? Because now I first have to logout and login again to get the correct values. Or is there a restart code?

Comment: Why are you storing passwords inside the session in the first place?

Comment: @Jack 'Cuz I want security vulnerabilities :-)

Comment: @Jack thats something I want to change and asked if its possible to skip all of that and if its safe to just store the user_id in the sessions instead of any other session values so I can change those things without running into any errors.. And I'm here to learn, otherwise I wouldn't be asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating the session with a new value for `$_SESSION['password']` should work (assuming you have `session_start()`'ed the session before you attempt to make a change.

Having said that, it's generally a bad idea to store the user's password in the session anyway, so this is a good opportunity to remove it. On the other hand, storing the user name is fine and could possibly prevent an unnecessary database lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the password from my sessions. I'm now storing the ID of a user because thats something which never changes.